# Covert molecule shortcuts to molecules

Tags: python, string, int

PLEASE no imports. Trying to grasp the fundamentals on python.
say I want a simplified input of a molecule to give me the actual molecule

For example:

molec('C3H8O3') would give me 'CCCHHHHHHHHOOO'

```
def desimplify(molecule):
    findnum = 0
    findchar = 0
    for i in range(0, len(molecule)):
        findnum += 1
        if molecule[i].isdigit(): #not sure if this is the right method
            findchar = findnum - 1 
            res = molecule[:findnum] + res * int(res[findnum]) + molecule[findchar:]
    return res
```

I'm sure I'm completely wrong, please point me in the right direction.

EDIT: fixed the typos

Comment: FYI: `import`s are part of the fundamentals of Python.  It's how you use Python's [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).  I see two problems here: there's a typo on the `findchar = fundnum - 1` line (fundnum) and your return statement isn't inside of the function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to provide you with a working example, this is how I would have implemented that function. I found the building of `res` a little hard to read how you did it, so I split it up. The comments should explain what's happening, in case anything is unclear I'll be happy to elaborate.

Beware this might not be the most Pythonic way of doing things.

```
def desimplify(molecule):

    # function-scope var to hold final result, won't be overwritten in loop
    result = ''

    # consume input token by token
    for token in molecule:

        if token.isalpha():
            # token under cursor is letter, append to result
            result += token

        elif token.isdigit():
            # token under cursor is digit, use as multiplier

            # we have already appended one token, so use one less!
            mult = int(token) - 1

            # apply the multiplier to the preceeding token in the input
            result += (mult * previous)

        # store current token for next iteration, when we might need to multiply it
        previous = token

    return result
```

Running this results in:

```
desimplify('C3H8O3')
'CCCHHHHHHHHOOO'
```

**Edit**: made it a little more Pythonic by iterating directly over the input string, without a loop var.

Comment: general molecular formula need more parsing : 'C10H22' or 'AuCl3' are legal formulas

Comment: This is completely true! To accomodate multi-digit indices, my solution could be modified, but when it comes to multi-letter elements, you'd need more elaborate tokenization for the problem-domain. That, or the code becomes quite messy with `islower` and the likes. Also, it'd make sense to check for valid elements, so you'd need to store a table of elements, too.